# Navigating through folders in Shell

Tags: shell

Im new to script. i have many folders in a directory. i want to write a script which goes to each folder, check files which are of x days older, move them to another location and then removing .

I have tried like the below snippet to navigate through folders .

```
    for D in $( find /path/folder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; do

 echo $D ;

    find -type f -mtime +30 -exec {} s3cmd put s3://path \;
```

s3cmd is for uploading files to s3

But it shows an exception as

find: ./folder/2013-07-29.tsv: Permission denied

I have tried using sudo as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the permission for folder using ls - l cmd to check the permission for User,Group and Others. You can also collect all those permission denied file name and then change the permission for all those files using chmod command and then perform the desired operation

Comment: there are too many files and folders and i have given permissions as well

Comment: Can you check the permissions on `./folder/2013-07-29.tsv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will check all files (not directories) from your current dir (.) that are greater than 9mins old:

```
$ find . -type f -mmin -9
./test/test1/file1_3
./test/test3/file3_3
./test/test2/file2_3
$
$ find . -type f -mmin -9 -exec cp {} ../bak \;
$ ls ../bak
file1_3  file2_3  file3_3
```

The following "copy" them to ../bak

```
find . -type f -mmin -9 -exec cp {} ../bak \;
```

You want days so, as you suggest, use `-mtime 10` instead (representing 10 days ago).

I suspect your error may be related to the following: `-exec {} s3cmd`. That is, you're asking to execute a command that is the result of find (no doubt ./folder/2013-07-29.tsv is one of your files, rather than the command you want to execute - which must be `s3cmd`?

If that's the case, rearrange your find exec:

```
find . -type f -mtime -30 -exec s3cmd put {} s3://path \;
```

You could also just zip up the found files, as follows:

```
find . -type f -mmin -9 | xargs zip ../bak/backup.zip
```

This is done through direct streaming of results (through `xargs` so would lower the diskspace required as compared to a move or copy (then zip, send).

Comment: Yes, the error was with -exec {} s3cmd. I have replaced as you suggested. It worked. Thanks a tonne :-)